change customscrollview scroll color
I am using CustomScrollView, and when I scroll to the end I get this, can it be changed color or can it be removed?

In short, my code is like this:
Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [

          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child:
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff50D2B6),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20))
              ),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 100,
              child: const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
                  child: Text('INFO APP', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ),
            ),


          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );

I've been searching on google for hours and still don't get an answer

It's an over scrolling indicator which appears when you reach end of the scrollable content and you are still trying to scroll.
in android it was a glow effect (appears in question) and updated to be stretching effect.
You can wrap your scroll view which is CustomScrollView with a ScrollConfiguration:
ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
        child: GlowingOverscrollIndicator( 
          axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
          color: Colors.yellow,// change its color here
          child: ....// you CustomScrollView
        ),
      )

Also , The child of the scroll configuration can be StretchingOverscrollIndicator:
ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
        child: StretchingOverscrollIndicator( // no more glow effect
          axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
          child: ....// you CustomScrollView
        ),
      ),,

So, You can now change the glow color and even change the over scroll behavior.
Hope it helps you.
